# Spring Data JPA. Hibernate 5. Conditional ManyToMany cascade handling

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-cascade

There are a lot of information and examples how to use `@ManyToMany` and this part is clear in general. I have not found elegant solution for my case. I know how to use work around, but I hope anyone knows and can share elegant solution or idea which should be used..

### Income details:

*Account* table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_table")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_seq_gen", sequenceName = "ACCOUNT_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_calendar_relation",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "calendar_id")
    )
    private List<Calendar> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
//...
}
```

is related to *Calendar*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar")
public class Calendar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "calendar_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "calendar_seq_gen", sequenceName = "CALENDAR_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "calendars")
    private List<Account> accounts;
//...
}
```

as **manyToMany**.

### Special restrictions

Loading account info I want to access all mapped calendars (for the account) but I'm not interested to have access to all *accounts* mapped on any accessed calendar via the *account*. I need situation to emulate some special behavior:

1. Loading *Account* for *User* I'm interested to access correspond *Calendar* collection.
2. Following **1.** via calendar I need to know only the *Account* (for current user it doesn't matter if *Calendar* has a lot of relations to other *Account*s).
3. Deleting *Account* all *Calendar*s should be removed in cascade.
4. *Calendar*s cascade deleting should be activated in *Account* deleting time in case if it was last *Account* for the *Calendar*.
5. Adding calendars to *Account* all calendars should be added in cascade way.
6. Restriction for **5.** only link should be added for calendars that were persisted before for other *Account*s.

### Question

All this cases handlers I can implement in spring services. But I believe this issue can be solved on hibernate level and I trust that solution must be implemented in most elegant way. So please help me to handle or suggest me please approach to manage this cases in best way (some hibernate annotations or other tools).

Comment: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/association-mappings-bag-list-set/
You should avoid List for ManyToMany association, also i think your mapping is wrong: i expected a collection in Calendar class instead of single Account

Comment: @Zeromus
Y, thanks - it must be definitely List. It is not implemented yet in project, I just preparing some documentation and planning services. To make clear plans I should know approach. Mapping can be fixed any time, but logic....